# Normalized Cross Correlation Operation

Tags: image-processing, cross-correlation, separability

According to my question about separability of Gabor filters in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210307/working-on-separable-gabor-filters-in-matlab), I want now to convolve my image with this separable filter by using the normalized cross correlation operation. Assume my `Gabor filter is G`, `my image is I`. My Gabor is separated into Low-Pass gaussian filter f(x) and Band-Pass gaussian filter g(y). Therefore the image is convolved with the Gabor using the following equation:

```
I(x,y)*G(x,y) = (I(x,y)*f(x))*g(y).
```

But I want to achieve this separable convolution using the ***normalized cross-correlation operation*** described below:

[image]

Where `^G` is the zero mean, unit normal version of the filter and `H(x,y)` represents a filter with all ones and the same size of the Gabor filter.

1) I didn't understand what is `^G`. What should be its value? what it differs from `G` ?

2) How the normalized cross-correlation is computed for the separable Gabor? I don't know if I use correctly the formula: `I(x,y)*f(x)*g(y) / I^2(x,y)*H(x,y)` . I don't think that it's true. because I didn't understand what should be the value of *zero mean, unit normal version of the Gabor*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what the paper described, I think $\hat G$ is achieved by standardized normalization on $u$ and $v$ before you implement the formula (1) on $G$:

```
x = -filtSizeL : filtSizeR; 
y = x;
u = x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta);
v = -x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
u = (u - mean(u))/std(u);
v = (v - mean(v))/std(v);
```

The filter is still separable after this normalization step, but I don't think you need to implement that, because it is just equivalent to select a different $\sigma$ value in the filter.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. can you show please the pages 3 and 4 from this paper: "http://cbcl.mit.edu/publications/ai-publications/2011/MIT-CSAIL-TR-2011-021.pdf"

Comment: Did you mean that I should only use I(x,y)*G(x,y)=I(x,y)*f(x)*g(y) ? without using the normalized cross correlation ? I didn't understand well your response :)

Comment: @Christina. Yes you can directly use I*f*g without normalization. It won't make a huge difference on your S1 results:)  Yet I edited my answer trying to show how the normalization is obtained

Comment: Ohh thank you!! but what is the advantage of the normalization ? and why they were used the cross-correlation normalization in the paper ?

Comment: So in the paper, they calculated the separability without using the cross correlation ?

Comment: i guess they wanted to eliminate the deviation of u, and v. N(0,1) is often applied to describe a distributions. But it won't mean a lot in the filter kernel design

Comment: you are right,  they did not use cross correlation in the later part

Comment: Okay, do you know how to compute the svd approximations using in this paper? If I open a new question about that, can you help me to write its matlab code ? :D

Comment: @Christina I will try to read that part, and maybe later today I would answer your new question. Thanks.

Comment: you are very welcome!